# Como puedo utilizar el ng-options en una lista

Tags: html, python, angularjs

Estoy tratando de llenar una lista de acuerdo a cuando se selecciona otra, cuando se selecciona un valor de la primera lista se realiza una consulta en la `BD`, y posteriormente con esa información lleno la segunda lista, pero tengo que utilizar el `ng-options` ya que si llega la información o los `datos` al archivo `HTML` pero no la puedo plasmar, dejo mi código para que me guíen a ver que modificaciones se tienen que realizar, gracias.

```
<div class="input-field col m7 offset-m1 ">
                                <select  ng-model="ticketActivo.canal_venta" id="canal_venta">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Canal Venta</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="canal in canales_venta" value="{{ canal.tipo_venta }}">{{ canal.tipo_venta }}</option>
                                </select>
                                <label>Canal Venta</label>
```

Comment: puedes agregar mas código de lo que tratas de hacer, no es suficiente para saber que quieres.

Comment: te puedo ayudar en algo?